# Média aritmética em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problemas para calcular a media aritmética de duas notas em meu programa em JavaScript. Quando coloco 10 na nota1 e 10 na nota2, sigo para fazer a media, mas infelizmente o resultado final de (10 +10)/2 está resultando em 505.
Abaixo o código:

```
//Pedido das notas
var nota1 = prompt(" Informe a primeira nota do aluno: ")
var nota2 = prompt(" Informe a segunda nota: ")

//Calculo da media
var media = ((nota1 + nota2) / 2)
    document.write("a media do aluno é: ", media, "<br>", "<br>")

//Pedido da frequencia
var frequencia = prompt(" informe a frequencia do aluno: ")

//Verifica se está aprovado
if (media >= 7 && frequencia >= 75){
    document.write(" o aluno está aprovado ")
}

else {
    document.write("<br>" , " o aluno está reprovado ")
}
```

Sinalizem pra mim por favor onde estou errando. Obrigado desde já

Comment: O prompt tá retornando "10", como texto e não como número. Aí fica  "1010" / 2 que por JS é 505.... Use Number(prompt(.....)) que resolve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobre o `prompt`:

> Por favor, note que o resultado é uma cadeia de caracteres. Isso significa que você deve, algumas vezes, converter o valor dado pelo usuário. Por exemplo, se a resposta deve ser um número, você deve converter o valor para Number: var aNumber = Number(window.prompt("Digite um número", ""));

Se você não converter, está fazendo "10" + "10" = "1010" / 2 = 505

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/prompt

Answer (score 1):

Quando inserimos os números 10 e 10 em campos de texto os valores retornados para cada campo também são texto ("string").

Existem outros métodos (além de Number) para contornar essa sua questão.

Função parseInt() -  Esta função do JavaScript analisa o argumento "string" e retorna um valor numérico inteiro na base especificada.

Função parseFloat() - analisa o argumento "string" e retorna um número de ponto flutuante, ou seja, retorna valores decimais.

Além dessa funções podemos de outras formas.

1- operador unário "+", colocando sinal `+` antes do prompt

```js
var nota1 = +prompt(" Informe a primeira nota do aluno: ")
var nota2 = +prompt(" Informe a segunda nota: ")

//Calculo da media
var media = ((nota1 + nota2) / 2)
    document.write("a media do aluno é: ", media, "<br>", "<br>")

//Pedido da frequencia
var frequencia = prompt(" informe a frequencia do aluno: ")

//Verifica se está aprovado
if (media >= 7 && frequencia >= 75){
    document.write(" o aluno está aprovado ")
}

else {
    document.write("<br>" , " o aluno está reprovado ")
}
```

2 - multiplicando o prompt por `1`

```js
var nota1 = prompt(" Informe a primeira nota do aluno: ")*1;
var nota2 = prompt(" Informe a segunda nota: ")*1;

    //Calculo da media
    var media = ((nota1 + nota2) / 2)
        document.write("a media do aluno é: ", media, "<br>", "<br>")

    //Pedido da frequencia
    var frequencia = prompt(" informe a frequencia do aluno: ")

    //Verifica se está aprovado
    if (media >= 7 && frequencia >= 75){
        document.write(" o aluno está aprovado ")
    }

    else {
        document.write("<br>" , " o aluno está reprovado ")
    }
```

3- Enfim, qualquer operação Mátemática os converte em número, por exemplo ...

```js
console.log(typeof("10" / 1));
console.log(typeof("10" * 1));
console.log(typeof("10" - 1 + 1));
console.log(typeof("10" - 0));
console.log(typeof(Math.floor("10")));
//Se você deseja converter apenas para números inteiros, um modo rápido (e curto) é o double-bitwise not (isto é, usando dois caracteres de til)
console.log(typeof(~~"10"));
console.log(typeof("10" | 0));
```

**O mais rápido** `"10"*1;`

Comparação de velocidade (Mac Os só)

Para o Chrome 'plus' e 'mul' são mais rápidos (> 700.000,00 op/seg), o 'Math.floor' é mais lento. Para o Firefox 'plus' é mais lento (!) 'Mul' é o mais rápido (> 900.000.000 op/seg). No Safari 'parseInt' é jejum, 'número' é mais lento (mas os resultados são bastante similares,> 13.000.000 <31.000.000). Assim, o Safari para a sequência de caracteres para int é mais de 10 vezes mais lento do que outros navegadores. Então o vencedor é `mul`

[image: comparação]